# What this code does? and Why my alarm is not stopped?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

```
Intent in2 = new Intent(context, ReminderService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, in2, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), 0, pendingIntent2);
```

**and the reminderservice.java include the following code**

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent in = new Intent(this, RemindBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, in, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), 1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I suggest you to just use only **RemindBroadcastReceiver**. There isn't any need of **ReminderService**

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Here you have set repeated alarm which triggered after every 1 second. You need to use **alarmManager.set instead of alarmManager.setRepeating**.

I think bellow code will be helpful for you:

```
 /------------------- CALLING PART
        Intent in2 = new Intent("MY_ALARM_ACTION");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, in2, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //alarmManager2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), pendingIntent2);
       alarmManager2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent2);
}
/-------------------



/-------------------------- RemindBroadcastReceiver ----------------
    public class RemindBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.getAction() == "MY_ALARM_ACTION")
            {
                // TODO Enter your code here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: and my alarm uses a Remindercycle functionality for user so that's why i m using it

Comment: Mean to say that do you want to trigger that alarm periodically(repeatedly at certain interval)?

Comment: means i want to repeat my alarm daily,weekly,monthly,yearly also ones.

Comment: if my application is close then i can i get the alarm ?

Comment: Yes but it your device is rebooted that that alarm will be flushed.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain what you want this code to do so we can't really know, but these are some errors I see anyway:

- I assume that `ReminderService` is a subclass of `Service`, therefore you should use `PendingIntent.getService` rather than `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`.
- In the first piece of code you call `setRepeatig` with the parameter `intervalMillis` = 0, and never calling `AlarmManager.cancel`, which I guess is an error because Android won't trigger your alarm forever, non stop.
- Why are you starting a service just so you can set another alarm to trigger something else  inside it?

Please explain the purpose of your code.